# How to build a Customziable Form in Angular

Tags: angular

I searched very long but i couldnt find any way hope anyone can help me.
For my projekt i need to build a Customziable Form in Angular
My Idea was to build somehow a template that you can customize and the user can select if the Adressbox must filled or not. etc or some text boxes for example for birthdate you can select if it should be displayed in the final Form.

For example.

```
Name:  
Address*: 
Birthdate:
```

Comment: Angular has the [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) module which is designed for this kind of work. See the [creating dynamic forms documentation](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-dynamic-forms) specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Angular forms are pretty versatile. I recommend you look into [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). A reactive form should be able to do exactly what you want.

You can use standard HTML inputs and style them yourself or you can use some pre-built controls from the [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview) library. For more advanced inputs you can build your own like [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/).